# Input doesn't work when "required" and "pattern" attribute is applied

Tags: html, css

Can you help me with this, I don't know what wrong. Input "**Fullname**" has applied `required` is ok.

(1) When I apply "required", "pattern" on input "Mail", the label doesn't hold the position as it's focus.

(2)Apply "pattern", don't apply "required, the label doesn't hold the position as begin. I attach an image, you can see more clearly [explanation img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj6uz.jpg)

https://codepen.io/quang-dang/pen/BOgBNM

```
<form class="wrapper">
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" required>
    <label for="fullName">Full Name(*)</label>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="mail" id="mail" name="mail" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required>
    <label for="mail">Email(*)</label>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" pattern="[0-9]+">
    <label for="phoneNumber">Phone number</label>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
  <button typy="sumbit">Submit</button>
</form>

/*
* LAYOUT
*/
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*
* FIELD > INPUT
*/
.field {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.field input,
.filed input:empty {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  outline: none;
  padding: 6px 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.field input:focus {
  border-color: transparent;
}
.field label,
.field input:empty ~ label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #999;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.field input:focus ~ label,
.field input:valid ~ label {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
}
/*
* FIELD > BAR
*/
.field .bar {
  display: flex;
  /*Start animation at center*/
  justify-content: center;
}
.bar:before,
.bar:after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background: #3498db;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.field .bar:before {
  left: 50%;
}
.filed .bar:after {
  right: 50%;
}
.field input:focus ~ .bar:before,
.field input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Post a *minimal reproduction case* (or [sscce](http://sscce.org/)) of code directly in questions.

Comment: I think that your code is working perfectly fine, can you please explain how is it stuck or what are the steps of reproducing this issue in your pen. And welcome to Stack Overflow community, we would appreciate if you could attach your code here in stackoverflow itself.

Comment: Change  `<input type=" mail"` to `<input type="email"` that should fix it also with its input type as email their is no need for pattern so remove `pattern` as the email pattern will be  implemented by the html

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="wrapper">
   <div class="field">
            <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName"   required>
            <label for="fullName">Full Name(*)</label>
            <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
     <div class="field">
            <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email"   required>
            <label for="Email">Email(*)</label>
            <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
       <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" pattern="[0-9]+">
       <label for="phoneNumber">Phone number</label>
       <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
   <div class="field">
      <input type="text" id="message" name="message">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <span class="bar"></span>
   </div>
   <button typy="sumbit">Submit</button>
</form>
```